# In GM Studio, how do I prompt the player for a password?

Tags: input, game-maker, text-based

I could make strings in earlier Game maker versions, but it doesn't work in the Studio version when I try.  The code I used:

When *Left Mouse Clicked* on *Password Bar*:

```
var str;
str=get_string("Crack the code!","");
if str!="pswrd" && str!="PSWRD" 
{
    check_answer=false;
    room_restart()
}
else
{
    check_answer=true;
    room_goto_next()
}
```

I want a box to pop up saying "Enter Password".  Then to enter the password, and if correct, go to a room, for example.  I am using physics in Gamemaker Studio 1.4.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Doesn't handle incorrect password?  Correct?  Throws error?  Goes to wrong room?

Comment: Whenever the action takes place, the Gamemaker closes and shows a white blank screen.  I am also using physics in my game.

Comment: Maybe you intended to use [`get_string_async`](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/asynchronous%20functions/get_string_async.html)? [Here's a discussion of a similar issue](http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=643143).

Comment: Please for an example?  I learn better like that.

Comment: Ah, it's a new bug in Gamemaker Studio. The string functions don't work whilst in fullscreen, but if I start in windows mode, it works fine.

Comment: How do I create a get_string code which can receive multiple answers?

Comment: You can implement a `get_string` accepting multiple answers by just using the [`switch`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/001_gml%20language%20overview/401_12_switch.html) statement.